# Weird 405 Method Not Allowed in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, http-status-code-405

I have a form for creating a user that contains email, name, and password inputs. The form also has 5 inputs (addr1-5) for the users address.

Submitting the form without the address fields filled in works fine, and creates the user.

However, if you fill in the address fields, it breaks by showing a `405 Method Not Allowed` response.

Route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/users'], function () {
    Route::post('/create', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@create',
        'as' => 'api_create_user',
    ]);
});
```

Form:

```
<form action="{{ route('api_create_user') }}" method="POST">
    ...
    <input type="text" name="addr1">
    <input type="text" name="addr2">
    <input type="text" name="addr3">
    <input type="text" name="addr4">
    <input type="text" name="addr5">
    ...
</form>
```

Controller:

```
class UserController extends Controller {
    ...
    public function create (RegisterRequest $request) {
        ...
        $address = [
            'addr1' => $request->input('addr1') ?? '',
            'addr2' => $request->input('addr2') ?? '',
            'addr3' => $request->input('addr3') ?? '',
            'addr4' => $request->input('addr4') ?? '',
            'addr5' => $request->input('addr5') ?? '',
        ];

        $address = (object)array_filter($address);

    $user->address = $address;

        ...
    }
}
```

RegisterRequest:

```
class RegisterRequest extends FormRequest {
    ...
    public function rules () : array {
        return array(
        ...
        'addr1' => 'nullable|string',
        'addr2' => 'nullable|string',
        'addr3' => 'nullable|string',
        'addr4' => 'nullable|string',
        'addr5' => 'nullable|string',
        ...
    );
    }
    ...
}
```

I really can't work out what the problem is. It's obviously not syntax I'm definitely importing the right classes etc.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the output of `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: Using your browser's `Network` tab, check what route it's `POST`ing to; maybe it's doing something unexpected, or performing a redirect somewhere it shouldn't be.

Comment: Just an FYI, You can specify the default as the 2nd param when using `input()` so `$request->input('add1') ?? ''` would be `$request->input('add1', '')`. Furthermore, since you're just going to filter the results down anyway could just do `$address = (object)array_filter($request->only('addr1', 'addr2', 'addr3', 'addr4', 'addr5'));`

Comment: [Here's the output of route:list](https://pastebin.com/raw/6JGmap5z). It's a bit messy, to be fair, as there's 3 subdomains and it's gotten a bit out of hand. Thanks

Comment: Okay, tested again this morning with no changes AFAIK, and it works. I love web development! Thanks anyway guys

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps you're forgetting the `{{method_field('POST')}}`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#form-method-spoofing

Comment: You only really need this if your request isn't `GET` or `POST`.

Comment: Yeah, that's not it. Thanks anyway